# Make Google voice / assistant listen always when ear buds connected?

Tags: bluetooth, google-assistant

My bluetooth earbuds on my Android S7 phone do not have a button to activate Google Voice Assistant for things like note to self Etc. If the phone screen is on Google Voice is always listening.

How can I set Google Voice Assistant to always be listening when I have these bluetooth earbuds in? 
Or how would I have it always be listening anytime wired earbuds are connected?

Comment: Try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en_IN) automation. Trigger : Headphones inserted; Action: Voice search. Save macro and test

Comment: Pretty sure Google removed this feature so you have to buy a Google Home device